# Javascript/Html.. push button goes into currect tab not new one

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, random, web

I'm trying to make a random link picker -  When I press the button, the link goes in the current tab. I'm trying to make it so it will go into a new one.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomlinks(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
    var links=new Array()
    links[0]="link1.com"
    links[1]="link2.com"
    links[2]="link3.com"
  
    window.location=links[myrandom]
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Random Episode!" onClick="randomlinks()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from:

```
//This sets the location of the current window, which you don't want
window.location = links[myrandom];
```

To this:

```
//This says to open a new tab or window, based on the user browser settings, to the url
window.open(links[myrandom]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line

```
window.location=links[myrandom]
```

with

```
window.open(links[myRandom], '_blank');
```

Comment: The first answer opens it in a new window, mine opens it in a new tag because of the '_blank' parameter!

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document.
You also have to check your browser settings first. If they are set to new window you can click your whole lifetime and it will still be opened in a new window instead of a new tab.

These are the right attributes.

The target attribute can have one of the following values:

```
_blank - Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
_self - Opens the linked document in the same window/tab as it was clicked (this is default)
_parent - Opens the linked document in the parent frame
_top - Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
framename - Opens the linked document in a named frame
```

So, this means that the default value (without the target attribute)

```
window.location=links[myrandom]
```

is also working. Hope it helps that your scripts work lovely.